# What are the special plans on #mageStackDay?

Tags: discussion, magestackday

### Magestackday.

What a great step. Thanks for @sanderMangel and @AnnaVölkl for this great initiative (if they are behind the curton). I really looking forward for this mega hackathon.

Come on.. Let us do this. :-)

However I need to know the plans for this hackathon.

How is this is going to manage ?

Is there any personal interactions possible (via skype or whatever) ?

*This is important, since we can make this event to share our knowledge and grab new knowledge*

What about people who cannot physically available in particular location (I am from india. I know I would be alone when participate in this event. :-( But having an online support is better right ?)

Do questions divide into different category so that people who are more interested to a particular category can answer that section ?

Is there any special plans to make this event a great success ?

I know lot of people would have other doubts too. Let us make this question to share those doubt and make a plan. I think 140 character limitation on twitter may break a useful communication.

Please share your thoughts and answer.

Comment: Hey there, we started a thread here before: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/393/cleaning-up-magento-stackexchange-com-join-magestackday
I think we should keep the discussion on one place, makes it easier :-)

Comment: @AnnaVölkl : Be honest, I didnt see your thread. Yes let us make this "one". What should I do with my above doubts ?

Comment: I will sum up arising questions. Plese have a look here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/a/395/231